# Certificate Enrollment web service in windows 8 Device MAnagement

Tags: windows-phone-8, mdm

I am developing the webservices to enroll windows phone 8 under company apps account i had successfully implemented the discovery and enrollment websevice and got the Base64-encoded PKCS#10 certificate request but not getting anything line written in the documnet of WP8 device management protocol under description of Certificate Enrollment webservice

"This web service implements the MS-WSTEP protocol. It processes the RequestSecurityToken (RST) message from the client, authenticates the client, requests the certificate from the CA, and returns it in the RequestSecurityTokenResponse (RSTR) to the client. Besides the issued certificate, the response also contains configurations needed to provision the DM client."

What is this CA how to forward the PKCS#10 to CA and get the certificate. Do we nee to purchase anything from microsoft to achieve the same Please help me regarding the same I am very new for Windows 8 so sorry If I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: I want to setup mdm solution for wp8.1 But I am stuck at initial setup for enrollment servers specially XCEP and WSTEP server. Can you through so light on their implementation as you have successfully implemented enrollment webservice.

Comment: The process is bit complicated and cant be explained here. Go through my discussion with Eric from microsoft here  once and let me know if you face any issue. http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/winphone/wpdevelop.aspx?ID=e57d02d8-b4b5-4ecb-92ec-c85b7a5a599d

Comment: thx for those links will go through these links. I am new to this env so my question may sound naive but Just to clear my doubt by anyway did u used certificate enrollment webservice provided in windows 2008 server ? or you just implemented by ur self and what is enrollment webservice can it be java / .net or any other

Comment: I have implemented all in java. I was also very much confused about these certificates. Its very simple, I have used BouncyCastle to generate my certificate. Catch me on IM @ Google plus if you would like to know more. +Piyush Agarwal